# Looping for odd and even number in java

Tags: java, loops

how do i  repeatedly ask the user to enter an input until the user enters a negative number. If the user enters a negative number or 0, the program will end?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OddEvenInt {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System. in );
        int x;

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer to check if it is odd or even ");
            x = s.nextInt();

            if (x % 2 == 0)
                System.out.println("You entered an even number.");
            else
                System.out.println("You entered an odd number.");
        } while (x % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to validate input, if the user enters wrong value or throws an exception you should return to the previous state. You shouldn't do it just in `main` method, Java is used to create objects and save data.

Comment: `} while (x > 0);` in the last line instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gotta change the while clause :

```
while (x>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<` and `>`

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 0;

    do {

        System.out.println("Enter an integer to check if it is odd or even ");

        try {
            x = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
            if (x > 0) {
                System.out.println("You entered an even number.");
            } else if (x == 0) {
                System.out.println("You entered 0, thats not negativ or positiv.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You entered an odd number.");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("U call this an Integer? :P");
        }

    } while (x > 0);
    return;
}
```

last edit: check if your input is numberic, if you want to check the error you can remove `//` from the catch-block

Comment: This will not solve the problem given the use case : "If the user enters a negative number or 0, the program will end?"

You need the exclusive > operator, or the program won't end if the user enters 0.

Comment: oh, you are right thanks, sorry, edited my comment :)